# combining two vectors in R

Tags: r

I have used the rep function to create two numeric vectors of unequal length.   I want to stack them in R. They need to be in a data.frame? How to do? See code below:

```
vec1=rep(1:7,each=1,times=12); vec1=as.numeric(vec1); 
vec2=rep(1:3,each=1,times=1); vec2=as.numeric(vec2); 
vec=rbind(vec1,vec2)
vec
```

They don't stack? I want vec1(84x1) followed by vec2(3x1)

```
vec # a matrix
```

Comment: maybe try `c(vec1, vec2)`?

Comment: what do you mean by "stack"? Do you want one long vector, or two columns with each of the vectors? (in which case, what should be in rows 4 and beyond of the second column?) Or maybe you just need a list that contains both vectors (`list(vec1,vec2)`)?

Comment: I don't understand what the output is that you want—you're trying to use a function that's generally for data frames, you're describing vectors, and then you label something as a matrix. Also, `vec1` is already numeric, so you don't need to convert it to numeric

Comment: I purposely tested what class R  was putting these vectors in. Vec1 was integer. I thought changing to numeric may be better for later processing. I needed more than a list. I am using vec as a sorting variable in a data frame. Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: I think you want: `vec <- as.data.frame(c(vec1,vec2))`

Comment: Still unclear. What do you mean by "stack", and what do you mean by "more than a list"? Can you add the output you're trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `append`

```
append(vec1, vec2)
```

---

If the intention is to create a `matrix` with 2 rows

```
matrix(list(vec1, vec2), nrow = 2)
```

---

If we need a `data.frame/tbl_df`

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(list(vec1, vec2), as.data.frame.list)
```

Or using `unnest_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
map(list(vec1, vec2), as.list) %>% 
     tibble(col1 = .) %>% 
     unnest_wider(col1, names_repair = ~ str_c('col', seq_along(.)))
```

Comment: How is this different from just using `c()`?

Comment: I guess you are referring to the difference between `append` and `c`. With default parameters there is no difference, `append` in fact calls `c`. The advantage of using `append` is that it allows the possibility of specifying an index through the argument `after`..